# C# insert method inside derived collection - binding stops working, but outside works

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, binding, derived-class

firstly sorry for maybe not the best title, I didn't know how to express it better. This also means I could've missed similar answered questions. Feel free to suggest a better one title for the others :)

My question is pretty simple.
I have derived collection limited to my object, it looks like this:

```
public sealed class TrajectoryCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : TrajectoryPoint
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public void AddPointUnder(T selectedPoint)
    {
        var newPoint = (TrajectoryPoint)selectedPoint.Clone();
        var nextIndex = Items.IndexOf(selectedPoint) + 1;

        newPoint.SetPosition(PositionBetween(selectedPoint, Items.ElementAt(nextIndex)));

        Items.Insert(nextIndex, (T)newPoint);
        RecalculatePointIndexes();
    }

    public void RemovePoint(T item)
    {
        Remove(item);
        RecalculatePointIndexes();
    }

    private void RecalculatePointIndexes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            Items.ElementAt(i).Number = i + 1;
        }
    }

    private Point3D PositionBetween(Point3D first, Point3D second)
    {
        return new Point3D(Math.Round((first.X + second.X) / 2, 3), Math.Round((first.Y + second.Y) / 2, 3), Math.Round((first.Z + second.Z) / 2, 3));
    }
}
```

and in my ViewModel I have this (Trajectory is bound to ListView itemsource):

```
public TrajectoryCollection<TrajectoryPoint> Trajectory
{
    get => _trajectory;
    set => SetProperty(ref _trajectory, value);
}    
public TrajectoryPoint SelectedPoint
{
    get => _selectedPoint;
    set => SetProperty(ref _selectedPoint, value);
}

private void RemovePointFromTrajectoryExecute()
{
    var selectedIndex = Trajectory.IndexOf(SelectedPoint);
    Trajectory.RemovePoint(SelectedPoint);
    SelectedPoint = Trajectory.ElementAt(selectedIndex);
    RefreshViewport();
}

private void AddPointToTrajectoryExecute()
{
    var selectedIndex = Trajectory.IndexOf(SelectedPoint);
    Trajectory.AddPointUnder(SelectedPoint);
    SelectedPoint = Trajectory.ElementAt(selectedIndex + 1);
    RefreshViewport();
}

private void RefreshViewport()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("Trajectory");
    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPoint");
}
```

Removing point works but adding doesn't. After adding one point, it IS added to that collection (I have verified it), but ListView won't show it - it behaves like it skips that added line (so it shows for example items 1,2,3,5,6...) and when I scroll down, it throws an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.

BUT. When I move that code from derived collection to my ViewModel, so it looks like this:

```
private void AddPointToTrajectoryExecute()
{
    var newPoint = (TrajectoryPointModel)SelectedPoint.Clone();
    var nextIndex = Trajectory.IndexOf(SelectedPoint) + 1;
    //new Point3D is PositionBetween
    newPoint.SetPosition(new Point3D(Math.Round((SelectedPoint.X + Trajectory.ElementAt(nextIndex).X) / 2, 3), Math.Round((SelectedPoint.Y + Trajectory.ElementAt(nextIndex).Y) / 2, 3), Math.Round((SelectedPoint.Z + Trajectory.ElementAt(nextIndex).Z) / 2, 3)));

    Trajectory.Insert(nextIndex, newPoint);
    RefreshViewport();
}
```

it works as it is supposed to and without any exceptions!

Could please anyone explain why this is happening? And what can I do to make working my Collection.AddPointUnder() method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: side note: `[i]` is much more readable than `.ElementAt(i)`. Do you by chance update collection from non-UI thread?

Comment: You think so? I see it both readable well:D And I don't. The only places I update that collection are in my ViewModel and inside that derived collection (add / remove). Not even from async methods.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason why TrajectoryCollection is still a generic class? And of course use `this.SomeMethod()` instead of `Items.SomeMethod()` for the equivalent of `Trajectory.SomeMethod()` in your ViewModel.

Comment: It's simple. I am deriving from generic collection for the first time and I didn't know how to make it non generic and accept only my object. And I've had more important things to do so I left it like that, but this is definitely on my "to make better" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is as follows: In your add you are inserting in the underlying `Items` collection. While the remove happens directly on the `ObservableCollection`. Use `Insert` or `InsertItem` on the `ObservableCollection` and it should update your view just fine. This is because the `Items` collection of the `ObservableCollection` is not observable.

Comment: You're right. It works. And I know why I used `Items.Insert()` instead of just `Insert()`. It was because I initially had `Items.Cast<TrajectoryPointModel>().ElementAt(i).Number = i;`, because `this.Cast<>()` (or just `Cast<>()`) was not working for me so I thought I need to use `Items` for all collection operations, I haven't tried just `Insert`. Thank you!